# Making a ragdoll in LIBGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx, 3d-modelling

So I am making a puppet program with LIBGDX. I made a 3d model in blender with uv textures and bones. I tried importing that model as a .obj but the texture was not there and as far as I could tell the bones weren't there(if they are there I don't know how to "use" them). I was wondering how I could import that model into LIBGDX with the bones and texture and how I could eventually make the model ragdoll. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exporting your model as a .fbx, that will make it so the bones are exported and the texture should work better. As for making it rag doll I have no clue, try using unity, from looking at your other posts it looks like you are trying to use the Leap Motion to make this puppet program as well. To get the Leap working in unity just drag the csharp.dll into your assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

For making a ragdoll effect in LIBGDX i would use the bullet engine. It includes ragdoll.

Heres an example of what it can do. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbKqnOHBQb4

There's a better one related to ragdoll that you can find in the libgdx bullet tests.